# How to make add/remove item in list view modify variables (int and double) in Android

Tags: java, listview, android-listview, global-variables, android-dialogfragment

I'll keep this short. I am creating an Android program to allow users to create test mech builds outside of a video game in order to determine if their build is possible in game before dropping money.

Currently, a user can click "add modules" to choose between a list of items in a dialog to populate the list view. Each mech is limited to certain variables. Such as weight, slots open, hard points, etc. Once your mech weighs so much for instance, the part cannot be added.

I am looking for a way to populate the list and change variables depending on the part chosen (I'm pretty sure a simple if/else statement will work here) and more importantly I am looking for a way to allow the user to click a list item and remove it from list along with removing the added change to the variables (weight, slots, etc). (example: Part A increases tonnage from 0/100 to 10/100 tons. User removes part A and tonnage drops to 0/100 again).

Thanks in advance!

Visual:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Je2AO.png) I do not have the rep to post images.